# How azure queue retries failed message?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have this azure function triggered by queue storage.

`function.json:`

```
  "retry": {
    "strategy": "exponentialBackoff",
    "maxRetryCount": 5,
    "minimumInterval": "00:01:00",
    "maximumInterval": "14:00:00"
  }
```

If `message A` fails,

- `message B` is processed and `message A` is put in the back of the `queue`.
- `message A` is retried until succeeded or reached `maxRetryCount` and `message B` with other messages waits until function is finished with `message A`.

Which one is correct?

Didn't find the answer in Azure docs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: `message B` is processed and `message A` is put in the back of the queue.

So, failed messages are put in the back of the queue.

The confusion is because Azure Storage Explorer shows messages sorted by original `InsertionTime` while the actual order of execution is different.

[image]

As you see `message b` have failed before and the order of the execution will be `d`, `e`, `b` while explorer window can easily confuse by showing only sorted by original `InsertionTime`.